# Trying to use HTML formatting in MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Mail

Tags: msbuild, html-email

In the same below, I cannot seem to get a bold around the $(Product) name, whatever I try. 
If I remove the IsBodyHTML, then I see the `<b>xxxx</b>` in my email. I tried both "True" and "true" for the IsBodyHtml value.

```
<MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Mail Condition="'$(SendMailSuccess)' == true"
   SmtpServer="$(MyServer)"
   To="$(ErrorEmails)"
   From="$(FromEmail)"
   Subject="Build succeeded for $(ProductName)" 
   IsBodyHtml="True"
   Body="The application %3Cb%3E$(ProductName)%3C%2Fb%3E was built successfully on ServerX."
  />
```

Comment: It's working now.  Dumb mistake, I had two routines, one for success, one for failure, and only one of the two had the IsBodyHTML on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. Dumb mistake, I had two routines, one for success, one for failure, and only one of the two had the IsBodyHTML on it.